# Python - parsing dict object into variables to record to database

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, object, parsing

I am trying to learn Python data types and I'm stuck at `dict` parsing. I have a `dict` object as below:

```
{'0': {'Group Name': 'e', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'fasd', 'DataType': 'data2'}}}, '1': {'Group Name': 's', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'd', 'DataType': 'data1'}}}, '2': {'Group Name': 'g', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'h', 'DataType': 'data1'}}}}
```

But I couldn't parse it for group `name`, `dataname` and `datatype`.

I tried `dictObj[iteratior]['Group Name']`, but I saw we cannot use numerical index in `dict` objects. So I tried `dictObj['Group Name']`, but it didn't work. What should be the proper approach?

I also tried it converting other object types, but it also didn't work.

*dictform* comes from the frontend as JSON as the structure above.

*icformkey* is the database queryset to be recorded in it.

```
for group in dictForm:

    if icformkey[iteration].level == 0:
        SingleQuery = icformkey[iteration]
        SingleQuery.name = group[str(iteration)]['Group Name']
        print("grup name", group[str(iteration)]['Group Name'])
        SingleQuery.full_clean()
        SingleQuery.save()
        print("group",  group)

    for input in group[str(iteration)]['Inputs']:
        if icformkey[iteration].level == 1:
            SingleQuery = icformkey[iteration]
            print("single query",SingleQuery)
            SingleQuery.name = input['DataName']
            SingleQuery.datatype = input['DataType']
            SingleQuery.full_clean()
            SingleQuery.save()

    iteration+=1
    output = {'result': True, 'error': 0}

return JsonResponse(output, safe=False)
```

Comment: Are you using string numbers like '0' at the beginning?

Comment: you can do ```dictObj['1']['Inputs']['0']['DataName'],dictObj['1']['Inputs']['0']['DataType']``` or use any **string number** like ```'0'``` that is in the list

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932446/iterate-dict-of-dict-in-python-efficiently-pythonic

Comment: Thanks all of you guys. I wish I had vote all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice, all the main keys of your dictionary are **string representation of numbers**: `'1','2','0'`. So, you need to specify quotes around the string to tell Python that it is a string.

Since the values are nested dictionaries, you can go on referencing the keys to get the values:

```
>>> dictObj={'0': {'Group Name': 'e', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'fasd', 'DataType': 'data2'}}}, '1': {'Group Name': 's', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'd', 'DataType': 'data1'}}}, '2': {'Group Name': 'g', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'h', 'DataType': 'data1'}}}}
>>> dictObj['1']['Inputs']['0']['DataName']
'd'
>>> dictObj['1']['Inputs']['0']['DataType']
'data1'
>>> dictObj['1']['Group Name']
's'
```

Comment: I edited my question. can you check the loop? it gives error at input part

Answer (score 2):

Your `dict` has Strings as keys, so you should convert your numerical index to a String instead:

```py
dictObj['0']['Group Name'] # returns 'e'
```

To convert your integer indices to strings, you can use `str` as follows:

```py
a = 3 # 3
string_a = str(a) # '3'

# for your object
dictObj[str(0)]['Group Name']
```

Comment: I edited my question. can you check the loop? it gives error at input part

Comment: The word input cannot be used as a variable name in python, as it is used to start typed user input. If you'd change it to `input_value`, that part should work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a value, you need to do it this way:

```
print(dict['0']['Group Name'])
```

It will display this:

> e

But the way you use dict in not the easiest way.
For example, you can use int or float value for the index or your dict like this:

```
dict = {
    0:{
        'Group Name': 'e',
        'Inputs': {
            '0': {
                'DataName': 'fasd',
                'DataType': 'data2'
            }
        }
    },
    1: {
        'Group Name': 's',
        'Inputs': {
            '0': {
                'DataName': 'd',
                'DataType': 'data1'
            }
        }
    },
    2: {
        'Group Name': 'g',
        'Inputs': {
            '0': {
                'DataName': 'h',
                'DataType': 'data1'
            }
        }
    }
}

print(dict[0]['Group Name'])
```

It will display the same:

> e

Even better, you can use a list in your dict (and vice-versa) if your indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4....

This way, for example:

```
dict =[
    {
        'Group Name': 'e',
        'Inputs': {
            '0': {
                'DataName': 'fasd',
                'DataType': 'data2'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'Group Name': 's',
        'Inputs': {
            '0': {
                'DataName': 'd',
                'DataType': 'data1'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'Group Name': 'g',
        'Inputs': {
            '0': {
                'DataName': 'h',
                'DataType': 'data1'
            }
        }
    }
]

print(dict[0]['Group Name'])
```

> e

Answer (score 1):

Here is the generic code to access the required fields:

```
dict1 = {'0': {'Group Name': 'e', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'fasd', 'DataType': 'data2'}}}, '1': {'Group Name': 's', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'd', 'DataType': 'data1'}}}, '2': {'Group Name': 'g', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'h', 'DataType': 'data1'}}}}

for key, values in dict1.items():
    group_name = values['Group Name']
    for k, v in values['Inputs'].items():
        data_name = v['DataName']
        data_type = v['DataType']
    print ("Group Name: "+group_name+", DataName: "+data_name+", DataType: "+data_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try the following code**

```
 data =
    {'0': {'Group Name': 'e', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'fasd', 'DataType': 'data2'}}}, '1': {'Group Name': 's', 'Inputs': {'0':
    {'DataName':'d', 'DataType': 'data1'}}}, '2': {'Group Name': 'g', 'Inputs': {'0': {'DataName': 'h', 'DataType': 'data1'}}}}

 for key,value in data['0']['Inputs']['0'].items():
       pr**strong text**int(f'DataName: {key} DataType: {value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(dict[str(0)]['Group Name'])
```